# Siddhi Reading input jsonarray with each element with multiple fields inside

Tags: javascript, json, siddhi

I have an inputstream that is a json array, each element of the array has a lot of fields, around 50. I tried to read the json elements with a JavaScript function but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea of how to do it?

The error that I got with the Javascript function is "class io.siddhi.extension.script.js.EvalJavaScript".
If there is another efficient way to do it, I don't care to change my way and do it with the other way.